# Android app with daily notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm making an android application.... and I've been trying to write the code for a daily notification set for a specific time of day. At first, I really thought this would be an easy task, almost every app in the play store has a timed notification. But after searching over and over again, all the methods and Youtube tutorials I've found failed to work for me. The problem probably lies in me, but I don't know what it is. All I need is a simple, elegant, easy to understand method (if there is such a thing). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the searching I've done has gotten me this far... but still without any luck:

This method is in my MainActivity class and is called only the first time the app is launched to set the alarm...

```
private void alarmMethod() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

    // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
    // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
```

This is my NotifyService class:

```
package com.OHS.example;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotifyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification mNotify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setSound(sound)
        .build();

    mNM.notify(1, mNotify);

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This Code.
**XML layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Android Alarm Example:\n\rSetup an alarm event after 10 seconds from the current time. So just press Setup Alarm button and wait for 10 seconds. You can see a toast message when your alarm time will be reach." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setAlarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSetAlarm"
        android:text="Set Alarm" />
```

**Main Activity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //used for register alarm manager
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    //used to store running alarmmanager instance
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    //Callback function for Alarmmanager event
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Register AlarmManager Broadcast receive.
        RegisterAlarmBroadcast();
    }
    public void onClickSetAlarm(View v)
    {
        //Get the current time and set alarm after 10 seconds from current time
        // so here we get 
        alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000 , pendingIntent );
    }
    private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast()
    {
          Log.i("Alarm Example:RegisterAlarmBroadcast()", "Going to register Intent.RegisterAlramBroadcast");

        //This is the call back function(BroadcastReceiver) which will be call when your 
        //alarm time will reached.
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver::OnReceive() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Congrats!. Your Alarm time has been reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        // register the alarm broadcast here
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.myalarm.alarmexample") );
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.myalarm.alarmexample"),0 );
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    }
    private void UnregisterAlarmBroadcast()
    {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); 
        getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I Hope this will help you, this worked for me.
You can always calculate and set the time when you want to trigger the alarm.
Happy Coding !!

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant... I can't begin to describe how thankful I am. All this time, I've been trying to start another activity which is responsible for show the notification, and that was causing problems. I never knew I could make the same class have the alarmManager and show the notification. Your solution is elegant and very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I do have one problem though.... After the alarm has been set, if I exit the app completely (from multitasking window), the alarm doesn't go off and I don't get a notification. I even tried removing the `onDestroy()` method but that didn't help. Any ideas how I can make the alarm go off even if the app isn't currently launched?

Comment: As much as i get your above  problem, do not remove the onDestroy() method, only comment the unregisterReceiver() method. it will be done..

Comment: Still nothing... Everything is working fine and the alarm is going off every 10 seconds up until I exit the app from the multitasking window, no notification after that. I thought the whole point of the `alarmManager` was to make something happen in the background at a specific time.

Comment: check if you are not calling UnregisterAlarmBroadcast() any where. because it should not behave that way.

Comment: Not calling it anywhere, I even tried it with the `UnregisterAlarmBroadcast()` method commented out.

Comment: Will it pop up more than once?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `AlarmManager` to schedule the daily notification. The document [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) provide a good explanation and example.

Setup the alarm.

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
    new Intent(this, MainService.class),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // set the triggered time to currentHour:08:00 for testing
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 0, pendingIntent);
```

Service to handle the alarm.

```
public class MainService extends IntentService {

    public MainService() {
        super("mainservice");
    }

    public MainService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        showNotification();
    }

    private void showNotification() {

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm title")
                .setContentText("Alarm text")
                .setContentIntent(
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                                SecondActivity.class),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setSound(soundUri).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: Much appreciated... but I've already tried that... I should have posted the code with my question. Sorry, I'm a bit new to this. I'll edit it in a second.

Comment: As you can see... This first part of code I got from the same document that you sent me.... And the second part I got from a different tutorial, I've tried making the notification appear when I press a button... and it worked, so the problem shouldn't be in the second part. Anything wrong in the first?

Comment: @OHS Your first part seems right. But the second part seems not very right. You shouldn't send the notification in the callback `onCreate`, it's called only once when the service firstly created. I guess, you didn't see the notification is because your service already created, `onCreate` won't call.

Comment: Okay... I tried it out, and everything seems okay except for the NotificationManagerCompat at the end.... it's giving me an error: "NotificationManagerCompat cannot be resolved"... And according to what I found on the Internet, I have to go to the Android SDK manager and update from there... so I did, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @OHS you can just use `NotificationManager` to see if it works or not.

Comment: Well unfortunately... I tried the 'NotificationManager' to see what if it works and it didn't... Then I went through the trouble to get the 'NotificationManagerCompat' to work, only to realize that it wasn't the problem.... My code is exactly like yours, didn't change a thing. But still no notification, I'm getting absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

as [alijandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4326936/alijandro) said if you want to have a daily notification in specific time you could use `AlarmManager` to schedule it and at that time show notification or if you want to get data from server, send a http request to retrieve your data and show notification to the user.
But if you want to have push notification anytime you want, you could use `GCM` (Google Cloud Messaging). Look at this [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/).